# Add custom variable in url Magento

Tags: magento

I want to add country name after store code. For example

```
The current URL for a category for the dutch store view would be;
      http://www.domain.ext/nl/category.html
 If the country is set to NL the URL should now be;
   http://www.domain.ext/nl_nl/category.html
If the storeview is Dutch (NL) but the country is Belgium (BE), the URL should become;
    http://www.domain.ext/nl_bel/category.html
```

I have the value of country code,I want to know how can I achieve it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: how  you have track Country??

Comment: I include library to get users country.

Answer (score 0):

Use **.htaccess Rewrite Rules** for that.

HTH

Comment: I want to use it only in category page.

Comment: I check match function of " app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php". but don't find any solution

Comment: Yep, you are on the right way. First create that rewrite rule with your htaccess so that "/nl_nl/" reaches the same URL as "/nl/" - This is important, otherwise you would create duplicate content and google hates that! Afterwards catch the request with the router, exact the same way you are doing it and redirect the current URL (/nl/) to the new URL (/nl_nl/) - pretty easy

Comment: Cant be edit it through overriding the router of the catalog module?

Comment: I can't use htaccess as I am fetching country name using ip address. Cant be edit it through overriding the router of the catalog module?

Comment: As per my search say, first override module so that it will add country to url then write htaccess rule to understand new url. Please comment

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you dont know how to rewrite with htaccess, you can make a "php rewrite" like this:

```
// First make a redirect in the Router Controller to new "/nl_nl/" URL, Then:

if(strpos('/nl_nl/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
     $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $this->getBaseUrl() . '/nl/category.html';
}
```

This will let you use your new URL (/nl_nl/) with the content oft /nl/